# Pspice error for vpulse

Tags: pspice

why am i not getting square wave in vpulse pspice?What could have been the possible error?
[image]

[image]

Comment: You pulse should have different V1 and V2 values. In this schematic, you are simply feeding your circuit with DC! Remember that the pulse has minimum and maximum values of V1 and V2, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Your low and high voltage values are the same at 0.5V. Change V1 to be 0 and V2 to whatever you want the pulse high to be. You may get unstable operation with your ideal rise times and fall times of 0.